# do branched covers have $C^{*}$-actions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X $ is a smooth complex projective variety, which is a branched cover of a smooth complex projective variety $Y$ over a smooth irreducible  divisor $D \subset Y$. Suppose additionally that $X$ is not isomorphic to $Y$.

**Question** Can X have a non-trivial $\mathbb{C}^{*}$-action?

Comment: If $Y$ is not required to be smooth you can take $Y=X/G$ for a finite group $G$ acting on $X$. For example, $X= \mathbb{P}^2$ and $Y =\mathbb{P}(1,1,3)$.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am interested in the case when Y is smooth. I will edit.

Comment: I believe that if you blow-up the rights points in this example it will work.

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no. For example, take a smooth variety $Z$ with such an action and $X,Y$ as in your question. Then $X\times Z\to Y\times Z$ has the same property, but with a $\mathbb{C}^*$ action on $X\times Z$. Equally easy to construct examples where there are no such actions.